# Finding the cross product of two vectors, but always yielding a vector in the same direction

Tags: vector-spaces

My question is with regards to a computer code I am developing. However, it is more closely related to mathematics so I have decided to post here. I have two vectors: one stationary vector (V1) and a rotating vector (V2). The axis of rotation of V2 is such that the two vectors become collinear at some point. I am trying to come up with a third vector (V3) which is perpendicular to both vectors, by taking their cross product. This is fairly easy. However, I would also like to have the third vector point in the same direction regardless of how V2 is rotated. Currently, V3 changes directions at 0, 90, 180, and 270 degrees, but this is an unwanted behavior in my code. Is there a formula to do this?

Ps. I was thinking of taking the cross product of a cross product of a cross product, but I cannot seem to find anything which works

Comment: When you want the vector to be fixed, then why computing it again and again? Compute it once and keep it.

Comment: Are you dealing with a 3-dimensional space? Can you elaborate more on "rotating vector (V2)" How exactly is it rotating? Visually, do you mean it keeps the length constant and draws a circle or a sphere around origin point?

Comment: I am trying to compute it again, and again because each rotation is a separate file, and independent from each other.@M.Winter

Comment: I am not too picky on the magnitude, I just care about the direction of the vectors at this point. Yes, exactly as you said. @NarekMargaryan

Answer (score 1):

If you take the cross product $V_1\times V_2$, then you will get a vector which changes direction at $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$ as $V_2$ rotates. This is what you don't want, is that right? One solution is to fix $V_4$ to be $V_2$ at $90^\circ$, and then set
$$
V_3 = (V_1\times V_2)\cdot (V_2\cdot V_4)
$$
which means that as long as $V_2$ is between $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$, then $V_2\cdot V_4$ is positive, so it doesn't change the direction of $V_1\times V_2$, while for $180^\circ$ to $360^\circ$, the product $V_2\cdot V_4$ is negative and therefore turns $V_1\times V_2$ around.

If you want the length of $V_3$ to be more stable, we could instead *divide* by $V_2\cdot V_4$ to make
$$
V_3 = \frac{V_1\times V_2}{V_2\cdot V_4}
$$
which actually has the same length for all the different $V_2$ except at $0^\circ$ and $180^\circ$ where it is undefined.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but unfortunately, I cannot easily use any additional vectors because V2 is always moving and its rotation may not be the same each time. Also during the rotation, each file is separate so I cannot rely on previous positions of V2. I know that this a hard problem, but was just wondering if there are any solutions.